# Embed a video object in html

Tags: object, embed

I have this assignement where I have to used export for web in quicktime pro 7. Then copy/paste the read me.html file into the body (exactly as it is), which I did.
However, I keep getting 3 errors when I run my .html through W3C and cannot figure out how to correct it.

I realized there are probably better way to embed object but this is how they want us to do it for this assignment. Can anyone help me correct these 3 errors please.
Many thanks in advance.

```
<object width="350" height="278">
    <param name="src" value="swiss/swiss-poster.jpg" />
    <param name="href" value="swiss/swiss.mov" />
    <param name="target" value="myself" />
    <param name="controller" value="false" />
    <param name="autoplay" value="false" />
    <param name="scale" value="aspect" />
    <embed width="350" height="278" type="video/quicktime" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/"
        src="swiss/swiss-poster.jpg"
        href="swiss/swiss.mov"
        target="myself"
        controller="false"
        autoplay="false"
        scale="aspect">
    </embed>
</object>
```

Line 1 : Element object is missing one or more of the following attributes: data, type.

Line 14: Attribute href not allowed on element embed at this point.
        scale="aspect">

Line 15: Stray end tag embed.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to embed a quicktime movie myself, and I looked to the Mozilla Developer Network for the syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object

I believe that the data attribute would take the place of href in your params:

`param name="href" value="swiss/swiss.mov" />`

would be:

`<param name="data" value="swiss/swiss.mov" />`

and the type in this case would be "video/quicktime":

`<param name="type" value="video/quicktime" />`

There is also an `<embed>` reference at MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed), but it covers only the HTML5 version of the element, which doesn't require a closing `</embed>` tag.

The reference at sitepoint (http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/embed) addresses the earlier syntax, and also says:

> "embed isn’t part of any currently recognized standard (it is included in HTML5 which is not yet finalized), so if you use it, your page can’t possibly validate".

That suggests that with `<embed>` you should probably focus more on actual behavior in the browser than the W3C's validation tool.